# How to use External HTML file in Karate.embed()?

Tags: javascript, html, reporting, karate

In my current karate reporting, I am trying to display a table format which looks similar to this -

| Key | V1 | V2 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | 1234 | 1234 | PASS |

The values of Key, V1, V2, Result are defined in my feature file.

Now, in order to display this table format in karate report, I am using **Karate.embed()** function -

`karate.embed(*HTML code*,"text/html")`

Instead of scripting the HTML code directly in **Karate.embed()** function and to avoid placing redundant HTML code inside this function, I am trying to store the exact same code in an external file and read it into my script -

```
* def HTML = karate.read('karatetabledisplay.html')
* karate.embed(HTML, "text/html")
```

When I do this,  I am unable to display the values of Key, V1, V2 and Result.

Is there anyway I can pass these variables into the external HTML file and then display those values in my report?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at the `doc` keyword. It is relatively new and can be considered "experimental". But I think it does exactly what you want: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#doc

```
* doc { read: 'users.html' }
```